# Need workaround against PHP 7.0.3 undefined function mysqli::set_local_infile_handler()

Tags: php, mysqli, load-data-infile

I am working in a project where it is required to download a big file from a remote server which contains pipe separated data for about 5 million records.

After downloading is finished it's needed to load data into a database. Currently I have been working with MySQL database so I have not considered other options.

I use object oriented **MySQLi** and I call a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query.
It takes between an hour and half and 2 hours to finish and I require a way to display progress and the only option I found was `set_local_infile_handler` method. Seems this method's purpose is to allow programmer to change the formatting of data before feeding it to the query, but being the only option I had found I want to use it for my progress purpose.

However all I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::set_local_infile_handler() in C:\Repositories\project\tools\loaddata.php:65
```

I am asking for:

- A fix to enable `mysqli::set_local_infile_handler` in my code
- An alternative with **MySQLi** to show progress while data is being loaded
- Other alternatives using PHP

I have tried a few ideas (only with a 100 thousand records):

- Changed from `new mysqli()` to `mysqli_init()` and `mysqli::real_connect()` but the only reason is because all examples with `mysqli::set_local_infile_handler` use the latter form.
- I uncommented `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On` at `php.ini` file, however I had no trouble running the code with the local infile query before that, but I expected that might make the troubling method visible. I stopped and started the server by the way.
- I called a second query

  `SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name in ('bytes_received','bytes_sent','innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data','innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data','innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed','innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests','innodb_buffer_pool_reads','innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests','innodb_data_read','innodb_data_reads','innodb_data_writes','innodb_data_written','innodb_rows_inserted')`.

  I kept all those variables because I haven't looked after each one exact meaning, I noticed only those variables changed meaningfully, but seems the last one might be enough. However I do this with separate files, I don't know yet if I can have two connections running in the same code and two threads to have the slowest running in background. In fact I was browsing for **php mysqli callback function** when I found `mysqli::set_local_infile_handler` reference.

I have been with this the whole day so I must had tried some other stuff but either I don't remember them or they are irrelevant for the moment.
Thanks in advance.

I dont see bugs in code, it works without local infile methods, but here it is:

```
require_once("connectvars.php");
$filepath = $_SERVER["argv"][1];
$bloqIdx=0;

$conn = mysqli_init();
$conn->real_connect($mysvr,$myusr,$mypwd,$mydb);
// $conn = new mysqli($mysvr,$myusr,$mypwd,$mydb);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error("SQL".$conn->connect_error,E_USER_ERROR);
    die("Connect Error");
}

function countData($stream, &$buffer, $buflen, &$errmsg) {
    global $bloqIdx;
    $len = strlen($buffer);
    if ($bloqIdx%1000==0) echo ".";
    return $len;
}
function getRowsInserted() {
    global $conn;
    $result = $conn->query("show status where Variable_name='innodb_rows_inserted')";
    $rowsInserted=0;
    if ($result && $conn->affected_rows>0 && $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $rowsInserted=$row["Value"];
    $result->close();
    return $rowsInserted;
}

$conn->query("truncate mytable");

$riStart = getRowsInserted();
$start = time();
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filepath' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED by '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
$conn->set_local_infile_handler("countData");
$conn->query($query);
$conn->set_local_infile_default();
$minutes = abs(time() - $start)/60;
$riEnd = getRowsInserted()-$riStart;
echo "Finished Loading $riEnd rows from $filepath for ".round($minutes,2)." minutes\n";

$conn->close();
```

By commenting lines:

```
$conn->set_local_infile_handler("countData");
```

and

```
$conn->set_local_infile_default();
```

code works but there is no progress info.

At http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-local-infile-handler.php valid versions apparently are (PHP 5, PHP 7)

If you really need to test the code the text file as argument can be something like:

```
1|one|alpha|C|2012-10-21 17:44:18
2|two|beta|C|2013-02-05 12:23:57
3|three|gamma|C|2012-12-10 07:18:09
4|four|delta|X|2012-11-27 11:51:32
5|five|phi|C|2013-01-07 14:03:29
```

And table script:

```
create table `mytable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `num` CHAR(10) NULL,
  `code` CHAR(13) NULL,
  `status` CHAR(1) NULL,
  `registered` DATETIME NULL,
  INDEX `mycode` (`code` ASC, `registered` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

Comment: Post the code that is causing the error. Perhaps you are calling it wrong.

Comment: You could fork a child process to do the work of downloading and importing the file, then enter into an infinite loop (each with a sleep() and some condition to exit on error or completion)... then check the innodb_rows_inserted (as you've mentioned that changes). Forking: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Ok, code added. I changed a few things related to private data.

Comment: About adding a fork process, how can that be done within php? I added my code, I hope I could get some code as answer. I started checking the link you posted, @AaronCicali.

Comment: `pcntl_fork()` doesn't work if PHP was installed as an Apache module, and that is my case. I am checking alternatives to `pcntl_fork()` but the only one that seems useful is to `exec` a second file code. The problem there is that the **progress code** needs to know when the **load data code** ends. Right now I run the code in command line but I need to include all this code in a web page later.

Comment: I've used "Bigdump" for importing large mysql files before, it essentially does what you're describing. It's possible though that the browser is handling all asynchronous calls. Maybe it will give you some ideas: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Comment: Thanks @AaronCicali, I read the Bigdump webpages and downloaded the zip file, I will check how it works. The current Bigdump usage doesn't work for me, but as you mentioned I might find some good answer in the wires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* just separate these into 2 different processes.

The first process is run every minute by a cron job and looks for the presence of some sort of trigger (like a tmp file). When it finds the trigger, it deletes the trigger (tmp file), downloads the large file, renames the file to a format that contains the total number of rows to be inserted, then begins inserting the rows into the database.

The second process is the gui. It provides the user with a button that creates the trigger (tmp file), then periodically checks for the existence of the download file. Once the download file is renamed to the given format by the first process, it can parse the filename for the total number of rows, then periodically query the database to determine the existing number of rows and present that to the user as a percentage complete.

Comment: If you'd like something a bit more responsive than a cron job, you can use inotify-tools (linux) to watch for filesystem events. This way you can actively watch for the trigger file to be created instead of waiting for the next cron iteration.

Comment: I've thought something similar except for the trigger idea, it seems dirty but functional. By the way I am working on Windows, unfortunately. Instead of using WAMP I installed php, apache and mysql separately, I have no experience with IIS and little and rusted experience with sqlserver. So for now the Task Scheduler is my cron equivalent which I use to run a batch file and meanwhile I use a second cmd terminal for checking progress. I will try this solution and check if it works on my service.

Comment: The solution, related to the requirement I mentioned at that moment, was to use 2 different processes, so that is why I marked this as accepted answer. At the moment this requirement became obsolete, the provider of the big file also allows communication via web service and this became the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I reported this case as a bug. Today a comment was added. This method has been removed.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77786